# Showing the Log(0) (or near zero) in a ListDensityPlot

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, logarithmic-scale

I have the following long function

```
j = (64 g1^2 g2^2 (0.5 + n2) Sqrt[κ2^2])/(16 g2^4 (Γ^2 + 4 ω^2) + (κ2^2 + 4 ω^2) (16 g1^4 + 8 g1^2 (Γ κ1 - 4 ω^2) + (Γ^2 + 4 ω^2) (κ1^2 + 4 ω^2)) + 8 g2^2 ((κ1 κ2 - 4 ω^2) (Γ^2 + 4 ω^2) + 4 g1^2 (Γ κ2 + 4 ω^2))) + (16 g1^2 (0.5 + n1) Sqrt[κ1^2] (κ2^2 + 4 ω^2))/(16 g2^4 (Γ^2 + 4 ω^2) + (κ2^2 + 4 ω^2) (16 g1^4 + 8 g1^2 (Γ κ1 - 4 ω^2) + (Γ^2 + 4 ω^2) (κ1^2 + 4 ω^2)) + 8 g2^2 ((κ1 κ2 - 4 ω^2) (Γ^2 + 4 ω^2) + 4 g1^2 (Γ κ2 + 4 ω^2))) + (4 (0.5 + nm) Γ (16 g2^4 + 8 g2^2 (κ1 κ2 - 4 ω^2) + (κ1^2 + 4 ω^2) (κ2^2 + 4 ω^2)))/(16 g2^4 (Γ^2 + 4 ω^2) + (κ2^2 + 4 ω^2) (16 g1^4 + 8 g1^2 (Γ κ1 - 4 ω^2) + (Γ^2 + 4 ω^2) (κ1^2 + 4 ω^2)) + 8 g2^2 ((κ1 κ2 - 4 ω^2) (Γ^2 + 4 ω^2) + 4 g1^2 (Γ κ2 + 4 ω^2)))
```

I wish to integrate `j` numerically:

```
intj = Table[{g1, g2, 1/(2 π)*NIntegrate[Evaluate[j /. {nm -> 300, n1 -> 1/10, n2 -> 1/10, Γ -> 1/100, κ1 -> 1, κ2 -> 20}], {ω, -150, 150}]}, {g1, 0, 40}, {g2, 0, 30}];
```

And doing a density plot with `x = g1`, `y = g2` and `z = "the integral"`:

```
dj = ListDensityPlot[Flatten[intj, 1], PlotRange -> All, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log", "Log"}, PlotLegends -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", PlotRangePadding -> None, FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black]]
```

I am returned with

[image]

Notice that my plot range for `x` and `y` starts from zero but given that I've Log-ed all the axes, the `x` and `y` axes both starts at `1` on the density plot. I presume this is because Mathematica can't take the Log of zero. It is crucial for me to show the  density at the origin. How should I go about doing this in a proper way?

**Edit**: I've tried starting `g1` and `g2` from `0.01` instead of `0` but the default step size is `1` so doing this shows an inhomogeneous disconnect in density colors going from `0.01` to `1`. Increasing the step size to `0.01` becomes intractably long for my computer since it is a `Table` with two-loops and the process is computationally expensive. How should I go about doing this?

Comment: Since you're using `ListDensityPlot`, I like to do something like:
`table1 = Flatten[Table[{10^g1, 10^g2, func[10^g1,10^g2]}, {g1, 0, 2}, {g2, 0, 2}],1]`
And then for your 0 points you'd do
`Join[Table[{0, 10^g2, func[10^g1,10^g2]}, {g2, 0, 2}], table1]`
... join another table for g2, then overwrite your tick labels, and don't use log scaling

Comment: @EricWilliamSmith Could you show me a working example of what you're saying?

Comment: @EricWilliamSmith Edit: Tried what you were saying but I don't know why you're joining the table with just `g2` with `table1` that has `g1` and `g2`. I am unable to replicate what you said. Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

```
j = (64 g1^2 g2^2 (0.5 + n2) Sqrt[κ2^2])/(16 g2^4 (Γ^2 + 4 ω^2) + (κ2^2 + 4 ω^2) (16 g1^4 + 8 g1^2 (Γ κ1 - 4 ω^2) + (Γ^2 + 4 ω^2) (κ1^2 + 4 ω^2)) + 8 g2^2 ((κ1 κ2 - 4 ω^2) (Γ^2 + 4 ω^2) + 4 g1^2 (Γ κ2 + 4 ω^2))) + (16 g1^2 (1/2 + n1) Sqrt[κ1^2] (κ2^2 + 4 ω^2))/(16 g2^4 (Γ^2 + 4 ω^2) + (κ2^2 + 4 ω^2) (16 g1^4 + 8 g1^2 (Γ κ1 - 4 ω^2) + (Γ^2 + 4 ω^2) (κ1^2 + 4 ω^2)) + 8 g2^2 ((κ1 κ2 - 4 ω^2) (Γ^2 + 4 ω^2) + 4 g1^2 (Γ κ2 + 4 ω^2))) + (4 (1/2 + nm) Γ (16 g2^4 + 8 g2^2 (κ1 κ2 - 4 ω^2) + (κ1^2 + 4 ω^2) (κ2^2 + 4 ω^2)))/(16 g2^4 (Γ^2 + 4 ω^2) + (κ2^2 + 4 ω^2) (16 g1^4 + 8 g1^2 (Γ κ1 - 4 ω^2) + (Γ^2 + 4 ω^2) (κ1^2 + 4 ω^2)) + 8 g2^2 ((κ1 κ2 - 4 ω^2) (Γ^2 + 4 ω^2) + 4 g1^2 (Γ κ2 + 4 ω^2)));
intj1 = Table[{g1, g2, 
     1/(2 π)*
      NIntegrate[
       Evaluate[
        j /. {nm -> 300, n1 -> 1/10, 
          n2 -> 1/10, Γ -> 1/100, κ1 -> 
           1, κ2 -> 20}], {ω, -150, 150}]}, {g1, 1/100, 
     4, 1/10}, {g2, 1/100, 3, 1/10}]; // Quiet

intj2 = Table[{g1, g2, 
     1/(2 π)*
      NIntegrate[
       Evaluate[
        j /. {nm -> 300, n1 -> 1/10, 
          n2 -> 1/10, Γ -> 1/100, κ1 -> 
           1, κ2 -> 20}], {ω, -150, 150}]}, {g1, 4, 40, 
     1}, {g2, 3, 30, 1}]; // Quiet
intj12 = Table[{g1, g2, 
     1/(2 π)*
      NIntegrate[
       Evaluate[
        j /. {nm -> 300, n1 -> 1/10, 

          n2 -> 1/10, Γ -> 1/100, κ1 -> 
           1, κ2 -> 20}], {ω, -150, 150}]}, {g1, 1/100, 
     4, 1/10}, {g2, 3, 30, 1}]; // Quiet
intj21 = Table[{g1, g2, 
     1/(2 π)*
      NIntegrate[
       Evaluate[
        j /. {nm -> 300, n1 -> 1/10, 
          n2 -> 1/10, Γ -> 1/100, κ1 -> 
           1, κ2 -> 20}], {ω, -150, 150}]}, {g1, 4, 40, 
     1}, {g2, 1/100, 3, 1/10}]; // Quiet

ListDensityPlot[Flatten[Join[intj1, intj2, intj12, intj21], 1], 
 PlotRange -> All, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log", "Log"}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", 
 PlotRangePadding -> None, FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black]]
```

[image: fig1]